# Limit of 100 items for graph statuses?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, limits

I'm working on a console application to download statuses and such from my own account -- nothing production or public. I'm finding that I can only get the last 100 statuses, but I was hoping to at least go a couple of years back.

I'm using the C# API, with something like:

```
dynamic response = Client.Get(string.Format("{0}/statuses", Secrets.FacebookUserName));
while (response.data.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (dynamic status in response.data)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    response = Client.Get(response.paging.next);
}
```

This works fine, but stops after 100 records.

I see the same thing when trying to use FQL:

```
dynamic x = Client.Get("fql", new { q = "select message from status where uid=me() limit 1000" });
```

Do I need to go down the road of exploring the  [batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)?

Comment: Did you try playing with limit parameter to get request? http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: I tried adding limit=200, but still got 100 back, however it came back all at once, instead of in four batches of 25. Seems like there's some hard limit of 100 somewhere.

Comment: By default the maximum data in one call is limited to 25, adding limit(upto 5000) makes it more to near about 5000 after which Facebook trims result based on privacy settings. Do also try the the Time based pagination to see if that might help. Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/) for the same

Comment: Not having much luck with until/since either. I wonder if my app is just not allowed to access more than a certain amount of data?